# Package name does not correspond to the file path

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio project is compiling as it should, but there's one annoying issue.
Android studio gives me this warning:

> Package name does not correspond to the file path

The file path declared in the source code is something like `com.example.<classes>`
but it asks me to rename it to `main.src.com.example.<classes>`
When I do that, it no longer compiles.

My source code is in the `src/main/src` folder.
My `build.gradle` contains this

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
```

Comment: Notice this critical and bizarre tip ... https://dayone.me/1Khzxa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your gradle.build file is in the main directory, it views the first `src` folder as the one containing the source. Try changing `java.srcDirs` to `['src/main/src']`.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio still has a lot of bugs to work out. Make sure that you package is the same in the `Manifest`

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of "main" in the package name.
Seen this error message when I used "enum" in a package name (not in Andorid Studio).
(BTW, "main" is not a keyword like "enum". )

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working on an **Eclipse project / not using gradle** build system, 
Using AndroidStudio IDE (after you validated that your path names are correct and the namings are right, if you still get this 'does not correspond error'):

1. Go into File -> Project Structure -> Platofrm Settings -> SDKs
2. Make sure that under sourcepath you've got your **src** folder listed, if not add it using the + sign

Mine is now looking like this:
[image]